# Collecting data of four related tables with one query

Tags: mysql, sql, eloquent

I have four tables in my database,`categories`, `posts`, `tags` and `post_tags`.

`categories` has one to many relation, and `tags` has many to many relation with `posts` table.

below snippet shows output of `describe` command for mentioned tables.

```
mysql> describe posts;
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id            | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| guid          | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| thumbnail_url | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| title         | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| content       | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| date          | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| category_id   | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
7 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> describe categories;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name  | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> describe tags;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name  | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> describe post_tags;
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| post_id | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| tag_id  | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

I'm going to create a json feed for posts, in this format.

```
[
  {
   "id": 1, 
   "title":"Foo",
   "category": [{"id": 1, "name": "Bar"}],
   "tags": [
      {"id": 1, "name": "foo"},
      {"id": 2, "name": "bar"}, 
   ]
   ...
   },

  {
   "id": 2, 
   "title":"Bar",
   "category": [{"id": 3, "name": "Foo"}],
   "tags": [
      {"id": 2, "name": "Tux"},
      {"id": 4, "name": "Quz"}, 
   ]
   ...
   }
]
```

I know I can achieve this result by merging two queries, such

```
mysql> select categories.*, 
    posts.id,  
    posts.title
from posts 
join categories 
where posts.category_id = categories.id;
+-----+-----------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id  | name      | id   | title                                                                                   |
+-----+-----------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   3 | Business  | 8070 | Demand for Marijuana 10 Times More than that for Ice Cream                              |
|   4 | Celebrity | 8067 | 10 Classic Quotes on Weed                                                               |
|   8 | Law       | 8056 | Proposed Rejig of California Medical Marijuana Laws – What Does it Mean for the User?   |
|  10 | Medical   | 8043 | Cannabis Oil – A Miracle Cure that We’ve Always Known About                             |
|  10 | Medical   | 8052 | Weed May Help Fight Cocaine Addiction                                                   |
|  10 | Medical   | 8073 | Cannabis May Help Treat Epilepsy in Children                                            |
|  15 | Tech      | 8079 | Matchmaking Apps for Weed Lovers a Big Hit                                              |
| 501 | Education | 8059 | The Quick Guide to Pruning Cannabis for More Yield                                      |
| 501 | Education | 8062 | Two Steps to Bring Down Power Costs When Cultivating Weed                               |
| 954 | Pets      | 8049 | Medical Cannabis for Pets – What Every Pet Owner Should Know                            |
+-----+-----------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

and some other query to group related tags with posts. Then (I use PHP) use a programming language to manipulate the resultsets and form the final data structure. But I'm curious that is it possible to achieve that result with one query?

I'm using Eloquent (not Laravel), so a solution with that ORM is also welcome.

P.S. I also have `Post`, `Category`, `Tag` and `PostTag` models.

**UPDATE: SOLUTION ATTEMPT**

I came up with a solution, [with patching this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17774479/4481312) to my query.

```
SELECT categories.*, posts.id, posts.title, tags.* 
FROM posts 
  JOIN categories on categories.id = posts.category_id 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN post_tags on posts.id = post_tags.post_id 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN tags on post_tags.tag_id = tags.id;
```

which gives me,

```
+-----+-----------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-------------------------+
| id  | name      | id   | title                                                                                   | id   | name                    |
+-----+-----------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-------------------------+
|   3 | Business  | 8070 | Demand for Marijuana 10 Times More than that for Ice Cream                              |   61 | BUSINESS                |
|   3 | Business  | 8070 | Demand for Marijuana 10 Times More than that for Ice Cream                              |  401 | Cannabis                |
|   3 | Business  | 8070 | Demand for Marijuana 10 Times More than that for Ice Cream                              |  402 | weed                    |
|   3 | Business  | 8070 | Demand for Marijuana 10 Times More than that for Ice Cream                              |  414 | Medical Marijuana       |
|   3 | Business  | 8070 | Demand for Marijuana 10 Times More than that for Ice Cream                              |  416 | Marijuana               |
|   3 | Business  | 8070 | Demand for Marijuana 10 Times More than that for Ice Cream                              |  441 | mcig                    |
|   3 | Business  | 8070 | Demand for Marijuana 10 Times More than that for Ice Cream                              |  484 | 420 friendly            |
|   3 | Business  | 8070 | Demand for Marijuana 10 Times More than that for Ice Cream                              |  604 | 420 cloud               |
|   3 | Business  | 8070 | Demand for Marijuana 10 Times More than that for Ice Cream                              |  607 | Medical Cannabis        |
|   3 | Business  | 8070 | Demand for Marijuana 10 Times More than that for Ice Cream                              |  721 | Medical                 |
|   3 | Business  | 8070 | Demand for Marijuana 10 Times More than that for Ice Cream                              | 1149 | Demand for Marijuana    |
|   4 | Celebrity | 8067 | 10 Classic Quotes on Weed                                                               |   69 | CELEBRITY               |
|   4 | Celebrity | 8067 | 10 Classic Quotes on Weed                                                               |  401 | Cannabis                |
|   4 | Celebrity | 8067 | 10 Classic Quotes on Weed                                                               |  402 | weed                    | 

.....
```

Which seemed ok for me. But when printing the results on to browser window, I saw 2 problems.

Results are grouped by tags (Which i can get rid of by some array methods).

Post ids are not shown on resultsets.

Comment: can you please elaborate what result? is that to update to delete or to display?

Comment: display. i will make a list of jsons as i've added above. simply, i need `post` details with associated `category` and `tags`.